# How can I use row_number over partition in outer select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, window-functions

I have a query similar to this:

```
select a.id,
       a.date,
       -- case statements using h.fields
  from advr a,
       (select id, 
               date,
               advr_id,
               advr_nbr,
               row_number() over(partition by id, date order by advr_nbr) adv_number
          from advr_hist) h
  where a.id = h.id
    and a.date = h.date
  group by a.id, a.date
```

One example of my many case statements:

```
max(case
      when h.adv_number = 1 then
        h.advr_id
      else
        ' '
    end) advr_1
```

This works perfectly, but it loads very slowly. If I remove the case statements *and* the `h` table, everything is fast. If I just query out the `h` select statement, everything is fast. Yet joining them makes it run very slow, so I've considered reworking this as a view.

How can I achieve the same results from the select statement, but have the row_number() `adv_number` field in the outer select statement? Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Have you tried pre-filtering the `h` table where adv_number = 1 and do a left join with the `a` table?

Comment: Maybe you should compare the query execution plan of both your queries to spot the key differences ?

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference, if you use it you have to pay for it somehow. By "fast" do you mean quick to select the first few rows or to get all the data back?

Answer (score 1):

```
with result (id,date,_id)
as (
  select id,date,
          case when row_number() over(partition by id, date order by advr_nbr)=1
               then 1 else 0 end as [_id]
          from advr_hist) 
select id,date from result
where _id=1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When putting code in an answer, you can press the 'code formatting' button to preserve the spacing of your code, rather than having it as one big runon line.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted any execution plans.  Nor have you attempted to explain what your query is trying to do.   So all we can do is guess.

My guess is, you just want the details from the earliest row in the sub-query.  Your current implementation uses aggregation to do this, which will generate sorts and lots of CPU cycles.  So it's probably not the joining that's the problem, it's the filtering of the sub-query.

In which case, you could simply do this:

```
select a.id,
       a.date,
       h.advr_id as  advr_1
  from advr a,
       (select id, 
               date,
               advr_id,
               advr_nbr,
               row_number() over(partition by id, date order by advr_nbr) adv_number
          from advr_hist) h
  where a.id = h.id
    and a.date = h.date
    and h.adv_number = 1
```

If this does not produce the outcome you want you will need to  *edit your question* and provide more details.

> "so I've considered reworking this as a view."

A view is a convenience not a performance enhancement.